# How to stop MapContainer class in Codenameone from dragging/panning

Tags: codenameone

I am using the MapContainer class to display a google map on android.

How can I stop the user from dragging/swiping the map to a new location ? ie. want the map to remain fixed at the coords I have set.

I have tried using MapContainer.setEnabled(false) but this only seems to work in the simulator and has no effect when deployed on a real android device.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

The panning is handled in the native map which handles its own events. Since those events happen on the Android UI thread Codename One can't intercept them without introducing a performance penalty.

You have two options:

- Intercept the events in the native Android code
- Fix the position after the fact

The second is much easier, just use a map listener to detect changes then pan the map using the API back to the original location. This might create undesirable UX though, in that case your only option is to use the native code.

You can do that by changing the [cn1lib code](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) and you can even contribute a feature back using a pull request. This should be relatively easy to implement in the native map as it should probably map to a setter/getter pair in the API e.g. `setPanEnabled`.

Comment: I had actually tried your second suggestion (reset position after moving) and you are correct...the map component flickers badly. I will look at the first approach/alternative screen design.

Comment: You can mitigate that by listening for the pointer release event and doing the motion back then